# Winforms .Net - Gridview fit to content form

Tags: c#, winforms, gridview, layout, resize

I have to implement the my first WinForms application.
The layout has been studied in order to implement TOP MENU with a main CONTENT AREA below.
I have created the main form that includes one panel for the top menu and one panel for the content area.

The problem comes from a first custom form that I call inside the content panel:

It contains an easy GridView, I want the form to be loaded fit to parent panel and also the GridView to be loaded fit to the content form...
How to do this?
I'm having some troubles with DOCK and ANCHOR properties...
Do you have some best practices?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
topPanel.Dock = DockStyle.Top; 
contentPanel.Dock= DockStyle.Fill;
```

And finally for your Content Panel

```
YourGridView.Dock = DockStyle.Fill; 

YourGridView.AutoScroll = true;
```

You can change your toppanel height

```
topPanel.Height = 100;
```

Comment: Ok, but how I manage the GridView in order to have it completely fit to the content form loader in the panel?
The gridview will also load lot of record and it must implement also a scroolbar in case the content oversize the height.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you are filling the whole bottom, top, left or right use `Dock`. If this is not the case and you want the size to increase with the form you should use the `Anchor` property.

Comment: Ok, thanks. Now I have another problem...
I have put a textobox and a search button at the top of the gridview.
If I dock the GridView, it overlays the textbox and button...
I have tried to dock left/right and bottom the Gridview but it get rendered outsizeing the gridview.
Its a strange behavior

Comment: Since it is not filling the whole top you should use the Anchor property. Or you can take a look at using a tableLayout which will let you organize your controls a bit more.